# How would I go about getting X and Y out of this piece of HTML?

Tags: c#, html, selenium-chromedriver

The HTML code is :

```html
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<string>X = 654</string>
<string>Y = 96451</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

I want to pick X and Y out of this, without using the numbers, since the numbers after X and Y are going to change.

So far I tried it by using XPath but for some reason it did not work, probably because I messed it up.

This is my code so far:

```
private void Background_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            ChromeDriver ChromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            do
            {
                ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
                x = ChromeDriver.FindElement(By.[This is what I don't know]).ToString();

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                TextBox.Text = $"x = {x}, y = {y}";

            }
            while (1 > 0);
        }
```

The X and Y variables are strings already defined.

Comment: That's XML, not HTML. There are classes in .Net in the System.Xml namespace for parsing it without using a browser

Comment: @JonasHøgh Thank you, did it with the System.Xml namespace, works perfectly.